# Deleting data from associated tables using knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I want to delete from an articles table using knex by article_id. This already exists in comments table as a foreign key.

How can I test that data has been deleted and how can I send that to the user.

I decided to approach this by writing a function to delete from both functions with a .then. Does this look like I am on the right lines?

```
exports.deleteArticleById = function (req, res, next) {
  const { article_id } = req.params;
  return connection('comments')
    .where('comments.article_id', article_id)
    .del()
    .returning('*')
    .then((deleted) => {
      console.log(deleted);
      return connection('articles')
        .where('articles.article_id', article_id)
        .del()
        .returning('*');
    })
    .then((article) => {
      console.log(article);
      return res.status(204).send('article deleted');
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

At the moment I am getting the correct data with the logs but I am getting a status 500 but I think I need to be trying to get a 204?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're probably getting 500 because of the typo here: `res.staus(204).send('article deleted')` (should be `res.status`, not `res.staus`).

Comment: thanks thats one thing sorted but functionality not sorted yet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called a *[cascading deletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE)* which is a form of [*propagation constraint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constraint).

These are better (and almost always) handled at the *database level* instead of the *application level*.
It's the job of the [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system) to enforce this kind of [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) assuming you define your schema correctly so that entities are correctly linked together, via [Primary -> Foreign key relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

In short, you should define your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) as such that when you delete an *Article*, it's associated *Comments* also get deleted for you.

Here's how I would do it using [knex.js migrations](https://knexjs.org/#Migrations):

```js
// Define Article.
db.schema.createTableIfNotExists('article', t => { 
  t.increments('article_id').primary()
  t.text('content')
})

// Define Comment.
// Each Comment is associated with an Article (1 - many).
db.schema.createTableIfNotExists('comment', t => { 
  t.increments('comment_id').primary() // Add an autoincrement primary key (PK).
  t.integer('article_id').unsigned() // Add a foreign key (FK)...
    .references('article.article_id') // ...which references Article PK.
    .onUpdate('CASCADE') // If Article PK is changed, update FK as well.
    .onDelete('CASCADE') // If Article is deleted, delete Comment as well.
  t.text('content')
})
```

So when you run this to delete an *Article*:

```
await db('article').where({ article_id: 1 }).del()
```

All *Comments* associated with that *Article* also get deleted, automatically.

Do NOT try to perform cascading deletions yourself by writing application code. The DBMS itself is specifically designed with sophisticated mechanisms to ensure that deletions always happen in a [consistent manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)); It's purpose is to handle these operations for you so it would be wasteful, complicated and certainly quite error-prone to attempt to replicate this functionality yourself.

Comment: how would you add 'cascase' on the del function with knex.js?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer Cascading deletions is something you set on your table relationships when building the database *schema*. You can't run cascade from your application code if the schema is not already defined to cascade when deleting.

Comment: so what is the solution for a case, when I want to be able to offer a partial delete and a full delete (that will delete all dependants)

Comment: Not sure, ask a question either here or on knex's issue list on Github. What you're looking for would probably be called "runtime cascade options".

Comment: May I ask, how to apply `.onUpdate('CASCADE') .onDelete('CASCADE')` on existing tables?

Comment: @David Use `db.schema.alterTable` perhaps if using knex.

Comment: Hi! I was trying to do exactly this, however if I follow this steps, when trying to delete  the "parent" row, I still get a foreign key violation error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MatteoCarpi Are you defining `onDelete('CASCADE')` ?