# How to fix post/put issue using knex, migration files and postgres database?

Tags: javascript, migration, knex.js

I am having an error with migration and my CRUD routes using a Postgres database and knex. In the database I am referencing a foreign key on my listings table and on the buyers table.

I got an error when I deleted a row that referenced a foreign key. I was able to fix it using `.onDelete('SET NULL')` Is there a better solution so I don't have null in the table?
Is there a method for update so the application does not throw an error if user tries to input a non existing key? Similar issue occurs when I try to post. I tried `.onUpdate()`  but wasn't successful.

migration file: agents

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('agents', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.string('name')
    })
};
 
exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('agents')
};
```

migration file: listings

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('listings', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.string('address')
        table.integer('agent_id')
        table.foreign('agent_id').references('agents.id').onDelete('SET NULL')
        
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('listings')
};
```

migration file: buyers

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('buyers', table =>{
        table.increments()
        table.string('name')
        table.integer('listing_id')
        table.foreign('listing_id').references('listings.id').onDelete('SET NULL')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTable('buyers')
};
```

This is my route just case it is better to handle the error at this point. But I read that it is better to handle at the database.

```
//GET all
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    knex('buyers')
        .orderBy('id')
        .then(buyers => {
            res.status(200).json(buyers)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err)) 
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    knex('buyers')
        .insert(req.body)
        .returning('*')
        .then(data => {
            if (req.body.name && req.body.listing_id){
                res.status(201).json(data)
            }else{
                res.status(400).send("This buyer did not post")
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error.message)
        });
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    knex('buyers')
        .select('name', 'listing_id', 'address', 'agent_id')
        .where({'listing_id': req.params.id})
        .join('listings', 'buyers.listing_id', 'listings.id')
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err.message));
})

router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if(req.params.id && req.body.name && req.body.listing_id){
    knex('buyers')
        .where({id: req.params.id})
        .update({name: req.body.name})
        .update({listing_id: req.body.listing_id})
        .then(res.status(200).json({message: "buyer updated"}))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
    }else{
        res.status(400).json({error: "buyer could not be updated"})
    }
})

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) =>{
    if(req.params.id){
        knex('buyers')
            .where({id: req.params.id})
            .join('listings', 'buyers.listing_id', 'listings.id')
            .del()
            .then(res.status(200).json({message: "buyer deleted"}))
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
    }else{
        res.status(400).json({error: "No buyer id found"})
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861921/2805154 - have you tried `.onDelete('CASCADE')`?

Comment: I tried ```.onDelete('CASCADE') ``` and it deletes the entire row associated with the foreign key instead of deleting just the foreign key.

Comment: As it's supposed to.

Comment: I could implement it so it would be better for the frontend design to have the row deleted. Any insight on the update/post error?

Comment: It certainly would be better for your frontend not to have to worry about the structure of the db and the side effects of deletion! As far as trapping invalid values, you could do a query before the delete to check for the existence of the record to be deleted and validate the parameter before the deletion error. Otherwise I'm not clear what you're looking for.